# Retrieve Data from IMobileServiceTable in a backend application

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I have a backend application which serves data for windows and android mobile applications, The Service application is hosted as a MobileService on Azure, I have a table named 'todoitem' that is associated to this Mobile service . Now I want to query this table in my controller to check if a particular id is already present in the table if not I will insert it into the table and also send a push notification to the client application. However I am able to insert the data into the table but have no clue of how to retrieve it.

This is the code for insertion

```
        public MobileServiceClient mClient1;
     public  IMobileServiceTable mToDoTable;
 mClient1 = new MobileServiceClient("MobileServiceName", "Key");
             mToDoTable = mClient1.GetTable("todoItem");

public  void Add()
        {
JObject jo = new JObject();
            jo.Add("Text", "Hello World");
            jo.Add("Complete", false);
             jo.Add("id", "123456");
            jo.Add("title", "New LED");
            var inserted =  mToDoTable.InsertAsync(jo);
}
```

what I want to do now is , I want to query the todoitem table of my mobile service , for example select * from todoitem where id="1234"

Any Help is much Appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving Data from a Imobileservicetable in a server project C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532337/retrieving-data-from-a-imobileservicetable-in-a-server-project-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Per your other question, here is the link you need: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/

Also, consider upgrading to Azure Mobile Apps!